# Android: Show Screen while loading

Tags: android, user-interface, screen

I am using AsyncTask to get data from a server and want to show a Screen while it is loading like this:

```
private class GetListTask extends AsyncTask {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(Start.this, Wait.class);
                startActivity(intent);
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... args) {
```

//here i get the data from the server

```
        d = getImageFromURL(Start.valuesArray[Integer.parseInt(Value)][7]);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
        double ratio = (double) bitmap.getWidth() / (double) bitmap.getHeight();
        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, (int) (width / ratio), true);
        return scaled;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Object objResult) {
        if (objResult != null && objResult instanceof Bitmap) {
            Bitmap result = (Bitmap) objResult;

            im.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in onPostExecute() I need to hide this "Wait" Screen again, but how do I do that?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Are you doing some work in the `Activity` that you start in `onPreExcute()`? Or it's just an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of starting a different activity you can show your image in a PopupDialog and close it in onPostExecute

Answer (score 1):

Use This Layout instead ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!--  Your actual layout. width & height fill_parent -->

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/wait_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/wait_screen"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Now on `preExecute()` show the waiting imageview and hide the actual layout.

And on `postExecute()` hide the imageView & show the actual layout.

Comment: how do I hide the current layout? and how do i correctly show the waiting imageview?

Comment: use `serVisibility()` method. For example - `findViewById(R.id.wait_image).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` will show the imageView and `findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id).setVisibility(View.GONE)` will hide your layout.